# Why am i getting IndexOutOfBoundsException here?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.util.*;

class two_strings_annagrams1 {
    public static boolean compute(String inp1, String inp2) {
        ArrayList<Character> hs = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < inp1.length(); i++) {
            hs.add(inp1.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(hs);
        for (int j = 0; j < inp2.length(); j++) {
            hs.remove(inp2.charAt(j));
        }
        System.out.println(hs);
        if (hs.size() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inp = s.nextLine();
        String inp2 = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println(compute(inp, inp2));
    }
}
```

When I use ArrayList or LinkedList I'm getting an IndexOutOfBounds Exception but when I use HashSet the code is working fine. What's the reason of exception and how the exception can be resolved?

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `hs.remove(inp2.charAt(j))` resolves to [`remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-), not [`remove(Character)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), because the compiler prefers expanding a `char` to an `int` over boxing it to a `Character`.

If you use

```
hs.remove((Character) inp2.charAt(j))
```

it will eliminate the ambiguity.